# Does Kafka write every single offset that is committed or does it happen by batch?

Tags: apache-kafka

As a message is produced and acknowledged by the leader (and the replicas), Kafka's documentation states that the leader will *commit the offset*.

I was curious:

- does it mean that every single message that is produced (and accepted by kafka) will increase a counter somewhere?
- in the old days when Kafka was hooked to Zookeeper for offsets, does it mean that all the leaders were constantly pinging zookeeper and asking it to increment the high watermark (the last offset committed)?

I want to believe that this was the case, because doing so by batch means we could "lose" offsets if anything happened while waiting to have a batch of a reasonable size. But in terms of performance I'm dubious. I have seen clusters with ~200 kafka brokers and 3 zookeepers, and all writes on ZK must go through its only leader, so that feels like a hughe performance bottleneck, hence why I'm asking.

Note: I'm asking about the log offset (what is produced), not the consumer offsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the context being Kafka replication, as a message is produced and
> acknowledged by the leader (and the replicas), Kafka's documentation
> states that the leader will commit the offset. For every single
> message that is produced (and accepted by kafka) will increase a
> counter somewhere?

Replication between the partition leader and followers happens in batches for efficiency sake in FetchRequest and FetchResponse messages. Each follower in essence tells the leader, in FetchRequest messages, that it has received messages up to a particular offset. This is the "batch receipting". The leader is able to increase the high watermark (HW) to the highest offset that each follower in the ISR has acknowledged. Consumers can only read from the leader up to the HW.

So, it's not a matter of incrementing a counter per se, but the high watermark is certainly updated. In terms of *somewhere*, the partition leader's high watermark is stored on the local filesystem of the leader in a file called **replication-offset-checkpoint**.

[image]

In terms of the latter, V2 of the Kafka replication detailed design states: "For each replica assigned to a broker, the broker periodically stores its HW in a checkpoint file."

In terms of Zookeeper storing the HW, as opposed to a Kafka broker, I have not come across that to date in reference material.

References:

1. https://developer.confluent.io/courses/architecture/data-replication/
2. https://medium.com/@darefamuyiwa/kafka-storage-internals-36606917629c
3. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+replication+detailed+design+V2